# Fix "Failed to decode downloaded font: (OTS parsing error: BASE: misaligned table)" error (Not using webpack)?

Tags: javascript, css, fonts, client-side, webfonts

```
@font-face {
    font-family: hiragino-w3;
    src: url(../../Fonts/hiragino-kaku-pro-w3.otf) format("opentype");
}
```

I've read a lot of pages for solutions, but all of them involve webpack, and I *don't think* the client-side app I'm working on uses webpack. And for some reason, when I try npm start inside the app, it works, but when serving the client-side code from a server, the fonts don't render.

I also don't believe this has anything to do with Chrome or the format of the file I'm using, because the fonts don't render in Safari either.

Comment: The error you're getting is that the font file you're loading is technically broken. Specifically, the BASE table directory information does not match the actual BASE table data, so the browser refuses to load the font, because that's going to cause _all sorts_ of problems when the font engine tries to use it. So get a non-broken version of the font. But now for the legal bit: you're not allowed to use Hiragino as a webfont. The only webfont-use that Screen (the makes of hiragino) allow is through TypeSquare. If you need just 1 font, it's free. If you need more, that will cost normal money.

Comment: Where do I get the non-broken version of the font? And also, the cost isn't an issue. But what do you mean by one font? I think all this app requires is hiragino-kaku-pro-w3 and hiragino-kaku-pro-w6

Comment: Just literally that? They have several plans, if you're looking to use a single of their fonts you can sign up for a free plan. If you need more than that, then you'll have to pay however much the plan that matches your requirements costs. See https://typesquare.com/en/service/web for that information. And the "how to get a non-broken version" is effectively that: you sign up with TypeSquare and follow their instructions.

Comment: So, how come the fonts render properly if I'm just running npm start inside my client-side app?

Comment: I have no idea what "running npm start inside my client-side app" means. `npm` doesn't run "inside apps", it's a CLI tool. `npm start` runs whatever task you have defined as `"start"` in your `"scripts"` section of the package.json file so: find out what that does, and update your post with that information?

Comment: Why are you being so aggressive? npm start just starts a localhost server on the client-side which renders all the desired pages. I'm saying when I run purely the front-end code, the fonts are being correctly rendered, meanwhile if I'm serving the frontend code from the backend, they do not, so I'm not sure of what the culprit is. I also find it hard to believe you have no idea what I'm talking about when I refer to npm start, so I'm not even sure if you're actually attempting to answer my questions.

Comment: No aggression: `npm` is a cli utility. You run it in a directory, but you can't run it "in an app". You run it on the command line, and it executes what you tell it to, so in this case it runs the script associated with `"start"` in package.json: please explain what that (chain of) script(s) does because it sounds almost certain that you have a build system set up, and you've not explained what that is yet, and without that information, there's not enough (accurate) information to help you figure out what's going on between "working" and "not working".